# How to do Recursive Common Table Expressions with insert into without repeating recursion (

Tags: sql, mysql

Please suggest how to do Recursive Common Table Expressions with insert into without repeating recursion.

Now I have a structure:

```
insert into table
with a as (),
b as ()

select * from a
join b ....

insert into table

with a as (),
b as ()

select * from a
join b ....

# I want to have a structure:

insert into table
with a as (),
b as ()

select * from a
join b ....

insert into table

select * from a
join b ....
```

I know what can be done through `union all`, but the request does not work because it is very large.

Comment: I don't understand why `UNION ALL` does not work. Does MySQL tell you that the query string is too long or what else happens? And if the first insert and the second only differ in `ON` and `WHERE`, you can probably solve this by using `OR` and thus combine the criteria.

Comment: I do not understand your question. If the cost of your recursive CTE is high and you want to use it with multiple different queries, why not materialize it in a temp table, which can then be reused?